# Merge object and array

Tags: php, json, object

I am posting some data in json format to a php script, this data needs to replace existing data that is in a session (array).

This is what I post to my PHP script:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => Bad 1
            [quantity] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [product] => Bad 14
            [quantity] => 1
        )

)
```

And this is my session array (`$_SESSION['cart']`):

```
Array
(
    [Bad 1] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 2
            [product] => Bad 1
            [price] => 1000
            [picture] => cms/images/bad.jpg
            [quantity] => 2
            [alias] => bad1
            [catalias] => baden
        )

    [Bad 14] => Array
        (
            [artikelid] => 11
            [product] => Bad 14
            [price] => 800
            [picture] => images/defaultimage.jpg
            [quantity] => 1
            [alias] => bad-14
            [catalias] => baden
        )

)
```

I want the posted quantity value to replace the quantity value inside the session array, but only for the correct product ofcourse. So if I post quantity '10' with product 'bad 1' only the quantity of key 'bad 1' needs to be replaced with that value.

This also goes when posting multiple products like in my example (the posted object).

How can I change the object into an array and merge (replace quantity only) it with my session array?

Something similar I tried but this only works for one posted value.

```
//Wanneer er een post waarde is vanaf het ajax script:
if($_POST['product']){
    //Stop de productnaam in de variabele $prod
    $prod = $thisProduct['product'] ;
    //Als er nog geen sessie bestaat, maak deze dan aan
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'])) {
         //en maak er gelijk een array van
       $_SESSION['cart'] = [];
    }
    //Als de productnaam nog niet voorkomt in de sessie, voeg deze dan toe inclusief de overige array waarden
    if (!isset($_SESSION['cart'][$prod])) {
       $_SESSION['cart'][$prod] = $thisProduct;
    }
    //Als deze wel voorkomt voeg hem dan niet toe maar tel de quantity op bij het bestaande product
    else {
       $_SESSION['cart'][$prod]['quantity'] += $thisProduct['quantity'];
    }
}
```

I fixed it like this with help from Don't Panic :

```
$quantityobject = $_POST['quantityobject'];

$arrayquantity = json_decode($quantityobject);

foreach ($arrayquantity as $object) {
    // Check if product exists in array
    if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$object->product])) {
        // if so replace quantity with posted one
       $_SESSION['cart'][$object->product]['quantity'] = $object->quantity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well first of all you have to write some code. Have you tried writing any code yet?

Comment: This doesn't really look tricky, especially since the session already uses the product as its key.

Comment: Possibly you are mistaking SO for a free to use coding service. **We are not** although if you hang around long enough a _Rep Hound_ is bound to be along soon

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got something similar, adding to the array but this only posts one value, and checks if it exists in the array. I'll add it in my question. But I am stuck on how to do this with another array/object.

Comment: Then you need to write a **loop**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it looks a bit simpler than you're making it. You don't have to convert to objects to arrays and merge them. You can use them as-is, just iterate the array of objects and update the session data for the corresponding product.

```
foreach ($posted_data as $object) {
    $_SESSION['cart'][$object->product]['quantity'] = $object->quantity;
}
```

You may want to include some code that checks that the product exists in the session array before trying to update it and handle that somehow, although this will create an incomplete product with only a quantity.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it with the check too. I posted the solution in my question.

Comment: You're welcome. I would suggest adding something that really handles missing products rather than just disregarding them. I assume that whatever/whoever is making the request is expecting to update quantities of all the products it sent, so not being able to do that for any of them seems like it would probably be an error condition they should know about.